# How do I force TypeScript to transpile prototype methods?

Tags: json, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to define methods on a class in TypeScript and then populate that class, but when I try to call the methods, it's saying that they don't exist.

TypeScript:

```
export class ColumnHeader extends JSONObject {
    // ...     
    isCountrySubtype(): boolean {
        return (this.columnSubtype && this.columnSubtype.toLowerCase() == ColumnSubtype.Country.toLowerCase()) ? true : (this.type != null && this.type.class != null && this.type.class == (new CountryType()).class);
    }

    isRegionSubtype(): boolean {
        return (this.columnSubtype && this.columnSubtype.toLowerCase() == ColumnSubtype.Region.toLowerCase()) ? true : (this.type != null && this.type.class != null && this.type.class == (new RegionType()).class);
    }

    isDmaSubtype(): boolean {
        return (this.columnSubtype && this.columnSubtype.toLowerCase() == ColumnSubtype.Dma.toLowerCase()) ? true : (this.type != null && this.type.class != null && this.type.class == (new DmaType()).class);
    }

    isCitySubtype(): boolean {
        return (this.columnSubtype && this.columnSubtype.toLowerCase() == ColumnSubtype.City.toLowerCase()) ? true : (this.type != null && this.type.class != null && this.type.class == (new CityType()).class);
    }

    isPostalCodeSubtpe(): boolean {
        return (this.columnSubtype && this.columnSubtype.toLowerCase() == ColumnSubtype.PostalCode.toLowerCase()) ? true : (this.type != null && this.type.class != null && this.type.class == (new PostalCodeType()).class);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Transpiled JavaScript:

```
class ColumnHeader extends JSONObject {
    constructor() {

    }
    isCountrySubtype() {
        return (this.columnSubtype && this.columnSubtype.toLowerCase() == enums_1.ColumnSubtype.Country.toLowerCase()) ? true : (this.type != null && this.type.class != null && this.type.class == (new CountryType()).class);
    }
    isRegionSubtype() {
        return (this.columnSubtype && this.columnSubtype.toLowerCase() == enums_1.ColumnSubtype.Region.toLowerCase()) ? true : (this.type != null && this.type.class != null && this.type.class == (new RegionType()).class);
    }
    isDmaSubtype() {
        return (this.columnSubtype && this.columnSubtype.toLowerCase() == enums_1.ColumnSubtype.Dma.toLowerCase()) ? true : (this.type != null && this.type.class != null && this.type.class == (new DmaType()).class);
    }
    isCitySubtype() {
        return (this.columnSubtype && this.columnSubtype.toLowerCase() == enums_1.ColumnSubtype.City.toLowerCase()) ? true : (this.type != null && this.type.class != null && this.type.class == (new CityType()).class);
    }
    isPostalCodeSubtpe() {
        return (this.columnSubtype && this.columnSubtype.toLowerCase() == enums_1.ColumnSubtype.PostalCode.toLowerCase()) ? true : (this.type != null && this.type.class != null && this.type.class == (new PostalCodeType()).class);
    }
}
```

I might need the prototype syntax for cross-system compatibility with parts that can't use ES2015 yet.

Comment: Have you set the `--target` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)?  You want to output ES5?

Comment: Hi @jcalz, sorry I posted my question a little prematurely before my scrum meeting started. I added the code that I'm actually using to populate the object, as that might be the offending code.

Comment: Where is `isRegionType` supposed to come from ? Because it's not in `ColumnHeader ` as you defined it in the question

Comment: Installed `extend`, defined `isRegionType` in `ColumnHeader ` all works as expected with the code you provide

Comment: Sorry @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, I was trying to post a minimalist example because I didn't want to spam my question with what's essentially the same boilerplate method 5 times, and I copied the code wrong. Let me try something else.

Comment: Alright, I changed to [node.extend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node.extend) and set deep copy to `true`, and it seems to be working! Maybe it was how I was using extend or further up in the code I'm not showing. I'll revert the question to its original name and accept yours since I wanted that option open to me (lower ES version for cross-system compatibility). Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the `target` as ES2015 (or above). This is why the Javascript contains classes. ES2015 supports classes so there is no need to use `prototype`. You can target `es5` and have the old way of doing classes in Javascript. You can set this in `tsconfig.json` or in Visual Studio or at the `tsc` command line (depending on how you have typescript set-up). For `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6"
    }
}
```

Your error however does not seem related to this, probably at runtime `columnHeader` is not the expected type.

Comment: That seems like it. I posted my question 3 seconds before my scrum meeting started and forgot to post the code that I'm using to populate the object. I'm thinking that the `extend` function that I'm getting off NPM might be removing the functions from the object.